# Getting ValueError in keras for unknown reason

Tags: python, keras

I'm running the following keras model

```
input_profile = Input(shape=(23, 23, 1)) 
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_profile)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_profile, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

X_GTEx = np.load('GTEx_X_float64.npy')
x_train = X_GTEx
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (5207, 23, 23, 1))
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,\
                epochs=50, batch_size=127,\
                shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_train, x_train),\
                callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder')])
```

And running it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_7 to have shape (20, 20, 1) but got array with shape (23, 23, 1)
```

Clearly, I haven't set anything with shape `(20,20,1)`. What's wrong with my program?

Comment: Errors don't come for no reason :)

Answer (score 0):

The length of every dimension of input is odd. This makes the `MaxPooling2D` layer down-samples the tensor with a `floor` operator.

In your model with `Input(shape=(23, 23, 1))`, the dimension changes of tensor after every `MaxPooling2D` layer will be `23 to 11` `11 to 5`.

Then two `UpSampling` layers upsample the `(5, 5, 1)` tensor to `(20, 20, 1)`, but the model need a tensor with the same shape as input.